# An identity of operator norms and de Leeuw's theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, operator-theory

Let $$Hf(x_1,x_2)=p.v.\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x_1-t,x_2-S(x_1,x_1-t))\frac{dt}{t},$$
$$T_\lambda f(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{|x-y|\ge\epsilon}e^{i\lambda S(x,y)}(x-y)^{-1}f(y)dy, $$ where $S(x,y)$ is a suitable real-valued function vanishing on the diagonal. In the paper [MAXIMAL FUNCTIONS AND HILBERT
TRANSFORMS ALONG VARIABLE FLAT CURVES](http://intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/1999/0006/0002/MRL-1999-0006-0002-a012.pdf) (p.238), the authors point out an identity
$$ \sup_{\lambda\in \mathbb{R}}\|T_\lambda\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})}=\|H\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)},$$
by applying Plancherel's theorem and the relation $$F_2H(x_1,\lambda)=T_\lambda(F_2f(\cdot,\lambda))(x_1),$$ where $F_2$ is the Fourier transform in the second variable.

I know how to show one direction$$ \sup_{\lambda\in \mathbb{R}}\|T_\lambda\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})}\ge\|H\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}.$$ Indeed, $$\iint |Hf(x_1,x_2)|^2dx_1dx_2=\iint|F_2Hf(x_1,\lambda)|^2dx_1d\lambda\\=\iint|T_\lambda(F_2f(\cdot,\lambda))(x_1)|^2dx_1d\lambda=\int\|T_\lambda(F_2f(\cdot,\lambda))\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}^2d\lambda\\\le\int\|T_\lambda\|^2\|f(\cdot,\lambda)\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}^2d\lambda\le\sup_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}}\|T_\lambda\|^2\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}^2.
$$
**My questions:**
(1) How to show the other direction $``\le"$?

(2)Moreover, the authors claim that $$ \sup_{\lambda\in \mathbb{R}}\|T_\lambda\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})\to L^p(\mathbb{R})}\le\|H\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)\to L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)},\ 1<p<\infty,$$ by using a variant of de Leeuw's theorem. What is de Leeuw's theorem? I can not find any reference on de Leeuw's theorem directly related to it.

Comment: Karel de Leeuw, On $L_p$ multipliers, Ann. of Math. (2) 81 (1965), 364–379.